# PHP Notice Undefined index. Searching alternative way

Tags: php, post, isset

I've tried alternative ways from similar questions but didn't get any good result. I've also tried `var_dump($_POST)` and `isset()` methods too. My code is:

```
<?php
function inputFILTER($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
    $question="";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $str=$_POST['supportinput'];
    $question=inputFILTER($str);
    echo $question;
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello @JohnConde I've tried all them but didnt get any happy result. Line: Notice: Undefined index: supportinput in ...\live.php on line 12

Comment: Can you show your html or form section here ! may be input name not the same

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="support_form" id="support_form">
<input type="text" name="supportinput" id="supportinput" onkeyup="showResult()" />
</form> The form is sent by Ajax Send method.

Comment: where is your submit button and its action ? post your `showResult()` code.

Comment: Hello @KrishR. It sends with Ajax code when on key down or up. It doesn't need submit button.

Comment: Fine, post your `showResult()` function code here.

Comment: function showResult(){
var xmlhttp;
var formData=$("#support_form").serialize();
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","/respondeo/live.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("formData");
}

Comment: change this `xmlhttp.send("formData");` into `xmlhttp.send(formData);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this,

```
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

instead of

```
xmlhttp.send("formData");
```

Javascript:

```
function showResult(){ 
    var xmlhttp; 
    var formData=$("#support_form").serialize(); 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
     }else { 
             xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
       } 
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { 
             if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {                                                      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
              } 
        }
       xmlhttp.open("POST","/respondeo/live.php",true);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xmlhttp.send(formData); 
}
```